# How to dynamically build function calls with different numbers of arguments in Rust?

Tags: function, dynamic, rust, interpreter

How do I take a vector of function argument AST variants, extract the values, and use them to instantiate a function call?

I am writing an interpreter that evaluates certain expressions.  Some of the expressions are function calls.  I am having a hard time figuring out how to translate the function calls AST to the actual call.  The AST gives me the function name and a vector of arguments.  I can lookup the function pointer to call from the name using a map, but passing the arguments to the function pointer is problem.

Rust does not have a splat operator (argument expansion).  I could pass them as a tuple and use destructuring of the arguments, but I can't figure out how to convert the vector of AST argument enum variants to a tuple of the concrete types.

I can't simply map or loop over the AST arguments to extract the values and produce a tuple.

I can use nested tuples to build a heterogenous list incrementally:

```rust
fn prepend<I,T>(i: I, t: T) -> (I,T) { (i, t) }

fn foo() {
    let x = ();
    let x = prepend(1, x);
    let x = prepend(2.0, x);
    let x = prepend(true, x);
}
```

But that only works because `x` gets shadowed and the new binding has a different type.  This won't work:

```rust
fn foo() {
    let mut x = ();
    x = prepend(1, x);
    x = prepend(2.0, x);
    x = prepend(true, x);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: user ExpHP in the rust lang forum answered your question properly: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-dynamically-build-function-calls-in-rust/29880

Answer (score 3):

You don't. Rust is a *statically typed* language and you are attempting to do non-statically-determinable actions.

Instead, all of your functions need to take in a collection of arguments, verify that there is the right number of arguments (and type, if appropriate to your interpreter), then call the appropriate Rust function with a fixed number of arguments:

```
// All of the panicking can be replaced by proper error handling.

enum Arg {
    Bool(bool),
    Int(i32),
}

impl Arg {
    fn into_bool(self) -> bool {
        match self {
            Arg::Bool(b) => b,
            _ => panic!("Not a bool"),
        }
    }

    fn into_int(self) -> i32 {
        match self {
            Arg::Int(i) => i,
            _ => panic!("Not an int"),
        }
    }
}

fn some_fn_wrapper(mut args: Vec<Arg>) {
    assert_eq!(args.len(), 3);

    let c = args.pop().unwrap();
    let b = args.pop().unwrap();
    let a = args.pop().unwrap();

    some_fn(a.into_bool(), b.into_int(), c.into_bool())
}

fn some_fn(_a: bool, _b: i32, _c: bool) {}
```

All of this will happen at runtime, as you want to create a highly dynamic language.

See also:

- [How do I pass each element of a slice as a separate argument to a variadic C function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50306894/155423)
- [How to pass a dynamic amount of typed arguments to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26555682/155423)
- [Calling a function only known at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30540807/155423)
- [How can I create a function with a variable number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28951503/155423)
- [Is Reflection possible in Rust, and if so how can I invoke an unknown function with some arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20445975/155423)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Indeed, I can do all that you propose, except for the step that converts a vector of AST enum variants (e.g. `vec![Arg::Bool(true), Arg::Float(2.0),  Arg::Int(1)])` to a heterogenous collection of values (e.g. `(true, 2.0, 1)` or `(true, (2.0, (1,)))` to pass the function.

I can look up the function signature in a map.  I can lookup the function pointer in different maps based on the signature.  And I can call the functions, up to some number of supported arguments.  But that crucial step is where I am stuck.

Comment: Why not? [Just write the code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=87c2725d8bccb78322dab9429f410111)

Comment: Yes, you can take a `Vec<Arg>` and convert it to a tuple.  The issue is how to do so generically, for potentially any combination of types in the tuple.

E.g., there are a number of built-in functions with different signature types, some take (i32), some (i32, f64), some (&str, bool, i32), etc.  Given a `Function(String,Vec<Arg>)`, how to generically take that `Vec<Arg>` and produce a tuple or `HList` that conforms to the function signature.

Implement something like `do_it` for all possible combination of argument types and argument numbers up to some limit, and then select the right one?